# Should Floating-Point RNG be preciser near 0?

Tags: haskell, random, floating-point, precision

The Floating-Point RNG from `System.Random` looks simple, yet inaccurate to me:

```
instance Random Double where
  randomR = randomRFloating
  random rng     = 
    case random rng of 
      (x,rng') -> 
          -- We use 53 bits of randomness corresponding to the 53 bit significand:
          ((fromIntegral (mask53 .&. (x::Int64)) :: Double)  
       /  fromIntegral twoto53, rng')
   where 
    twoto53 = (2::Int64) ^ (53::Int64)
    mask53 = twoto53 - 1
```

Though this RNG indeed produces FP numbers uniformly, there is one thing that I'm doubtful of: **There are some numbers in the range that the RNG cannot produce.**

Specifically, "too" precise numbers. For example, this RNG can produce (represented as binary IEEE Double-precision FP; sign, exponent, and then mantissa):

```
0 01111111101 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which is exactly ¼, but cannot produce:

```
0 01111111101 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

because that last `1` (barely) has too much precision.

I doubted if this should happen, so I wrote my own uniform FP RNG:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Bifunctor
import System.Random

randomFloat1to2 :: (RandomGen g, Random a, RealFloat a) => g -> (a, g) -- Uniformly generates random Float among [1,2)
randomFloat1to2 g = first (1+) (random g)

randomFloatExp :: forall a g. (RandomGen g, Random a, RealFloat a) => Int -> g -> (a, g) -- Uniformly generates random Float among [0, 2^(exp+1))
randomFloatExp exp g = let
    (minexp, _) = floatRange (0 :: a)
    (upperHalf, g') = random g
    in if exp == minexp
        then (0, g') -- Denormal numbers treated as 0
        else if upperHalf
            then first (2^^exp *) (randomFloat1to2 g')
            else randomFloatExp (exp-1) g'

randomFloat :: (RandomGen g, Random a, RealFloat a) => g -> (a, g) -- Uniformly generates random Float among [0,1)
randomFloat = randomFloatExp (-1)
```

Explanation:

Among the `Double` numbers in the range [0,1), all numbers in [½,1) have IEEE exponent `01111111110` while the others have lower one. So the RNG makes a coin flip:

If a head comes out, the RNG picks a random number among [½,1) via multiplying ½ and a random number among [1,2). Since the default `random` effectively picks a random mantissa, we can add 1 to it to make a uniform RNG for the range [1,2).

If not, the RNG makes recursion through [¼,½), [⅛,¼), and so on, until the range is denormal.

Can my version be considered as a better version?

Comment: The quality of software is how well it serves the goal to be achieved. What is the goal to be achieved in this case? If the client of the generator just wants some samples from an evenly spaced distribution, then the first generator is good. If you want to model a uniform distribution over the reals as finely as possible, then maybe this is better. But, if we picked a sample from a uniform distribution over the reals and rounded it to the nearest representable value, we would not end up with your distribution, because a point at the low end of a binade (½, ¼,…) should be less frequent…

Comment: … than points inside the binade, because, for a point inside the binade, all points in (x−½u, x+½u) round to representable value x, where u is the ULP for the binande (and the endpoints may or may not be included, depending on the low bit of x), but, for x the low endpoint, only points in (x−¼u, x+½u) round to x, because, below x-¼u, the high value in the next lower binade is closer. Another consideration is how the client is going to use the samples. A common thing to do is multiply by some b and add a, so scale to an interval [a, a+b).…

Comment: … Even with a and b merely 1, your fine-tuning goes out the window as low bits are lost when 1 is added. And the effects of rounding during the multiply and the add (with other values of a and b, not just 1) may skew the distribution. So, again, what generator is good for what application depends on the application.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "If you want to model a uniform distribution over the reals as finely as possible", yes, that's my goal. But since the RNG is supposed to be for right-open ranges, rather than "rounded it to the nearest representable value", it's "rounded it down".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should Floating-Point RNG be preciser near 0?

Depends on function goals as well commented by [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942734/should-floating-point-rng-be-preciser-near-0#comment90836013_51942734).

It is like asking if `tan(x)` is better than `sin(x)`: it depends on the goal.  Both give the same answers for small `x` yet differ in another part of the range.

---

> Can my version be considered as a better version?

A reason why it is not better: time to complete can be quite large in the worst case - even though it may be rare.

> the RNG makes recursion through [¼,½), [⅛,¼), and so on, until the range is denormal.

Recursion though [¼,½), [⅛,¼) to denormal can take *thousands of recursions*.

To help a tad, instead code could generate a random exponent, still recursively, yet faster (MSBit of n-bit `random` becomes exponent unless the random was 0, then a recursive call needed.)

This reduces the recursion by a factor on N (bit width of `random` number).

Yet a solution that does not potential recurse [scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20_(number)) of times, needs a different `random` to compute the exponent.

Comment: Though, since my original version had `O(2ⁿ)` time complexity (where `n` is the length of exponent bits of FP type) and you divided it by a constant factor, it will still be `O(2ⁿ)`. Also, if I generated a random single 2ⁿ-bit integer for the FP RNG, the time complexity will be worse `Θ(2ⁿ)`, since the system RNG can only generate integers with a fixed bit length.